# How to install package only for iOs or Android in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, package.json

I would like to know if it's possible to install a package only for iOs or Android in React Native ? I'm using tipsi-stripe for Apple Pay and there is some bugs with Android and RN0.61.5, and I don't need it on Android.

I tried to delete module from Android Studio and from packages.json and it's working but it's not clean, does someone have a better solution ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to add this in your `react-native.config`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  dependencies: {
    'tipsi-stripe': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Where to add this info? And where to add react-native.config

Comment: @DeepakPanwar this file will be in <your project>/react-native.config.js

Comment: The filename should be `react-native.config.js` and the documentation can be found here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/projects.md#dependencies

Answer (score 2):

You can't install package only for IOS but you can import it based on platform as follow:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

let ModuleName

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  ModuleName = require('moduleName')
}
```

Comment: It's good for importing based on platform but not for install based on platform