# How to install a package / library only for ios in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

am using ffmpeg-kit-react-native but i want to install it for ios only ...as it increases the build size 3X for android .. am not using it for android as well . is it possible to install it for ios only?
am on react-native@0.64.4

i tried creating react-native.config.js but it does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was react-native.config.js all along ... i was not defining package correctly .

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'ffmpeg-kit-react-native': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `<your project>/react-native.config`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  dependencies: {
    'ffmpeg-kit-react-native': {
      platforms: {
        android: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: this doesnt work this package still exist in android

Comment: @AdnanAshraf Then you can try conditional importing based on platform as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269215/14144599.

Comment: I have handled the import as well .. the point is to make sure the android side doesnt download/add  the dependencies for ffmpeg which increase the build size to 3x.